# Custom iterator of 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, 2d

Suppose I have a vector of vectors:

```
vector<vector<T> > matrix;
```

I want to implement `begin()` and `end()` methods so that the iterator returns the elements of `matrix` in a logical order ((0,0), (0,1)... (1,0) ...).

```
typedef typename vector<vector<T> >::const_iterator const_iterator;
const_iterator begin() const
{

}
const_iterator end() const
{

}
```

Usually when working with a 1D vector I just returned `vector.begin()`, but since this one is a 2D (and I never thought about how the `vector.begin()` method actually works) I'm not sure how to do it. Any examples/explanations about implementing custom iterators appreciated.